# I want to compare columns of two data frames to identify if caseid from one data frame exist in another data frame

Tags: r, comparison

I have copied year 2006 data into one data frame. I have copied year 2013 data in another data frame. CaseID is the primary key for both the data frames. How do I compare these two data frames so that I can find out the caseIDs those exist in both the data frames.

Example:

```
d1
123
234
254

d2
236
256
123

output must be:
123
```

I am using following code and I believe its the worst method:

```
for(i in 1:(nrow(AllYearsCaseIDs))){
  for (j in 1:(nrow(AllYearsCaseIDs))){
    if(is.na((AllYearsCaseIDs[i, "dat2013.CASEID"])))
       break

       if(is.na((AllYearsCaseIDs[j, "dat2006.CASEID"])))
       break

       if((AllYearsCaseIDs[i, "dat2013.CASEID"]) == (AllYearsCaseIDs[j, "dat2006.CASEID"])){
         output[i, 1 ] <- as.matrix(AllYearsCaseIDs[i, "dat2013.CASEID"])
         break
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `intersect` to find common Case ID's , `intersect(d1$column_name, d2$column_name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:

You can use `merge`

```
df <- merge(dat2013, dat2006, by="CASEID")
```

`df` is your merged data frame with `CASEID` exists both in `dat2013` and `dat2006`.

If you want to return `CASEID` that exists in both:

```
df$CASEID
```

Option 2:

```
dat2013$CASEID[dat2013$CASEID %in% dat2006$CASEID]
```

Option 3:

```
intersect(dat2013$CASEID, dat2006$CASEID)
```